# State of HTML5 Audio

Tags: html, audio, html5-canvas, html5-audio

I've recently been looking into doing some Audio processing and visualization in a web browser as a sort of pet project. Of course, I immediately googled to see what other people had done in this area. Most of the demos are a few years old. Many of the packages either don't work anymore or are (in my opinion) needlessly complex. The  tag doesn't seem to support anything which allows me to **access the audio data as it plays**.

Does anyone know if a simple way has come about which someone can create an event callback which fires every time new audio data starts playing within a given waveform?

Unfortunately the [Mozilla Audio Data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) doesn't seem to be supported in Chrome (which is the primary browser I like to use). None of the events properly register and they never fire.

I'd really prefer to not have to reverse engineer stuff like [this](http://www.grantgalitz.org/sound_test/) when all I want to do is create a very simple waveform display.

Any advice/recommendations for simple libraries or functions which I may not be finding would be much appreciated! I promise I've googled this for a few days now without finding any good, obvious solutions!

Comment: "callback which fires every time a new audio data starts playing within a given waveform", what does this mean?  Also, what you are trying to do *is* complex, so stop thinking that what you are finding is "needlessly" complex.

Comment: I'm used to being able to do it in an environment like LabVIEW or .NET where the code is fairly straight forward (especially in LabVIEW). What that means is that given a set of N samples is sent to the sound card to be produced by hardware, I want access to those N samples before (or while) they are sent.

Comment: So, you want to get the data post-codec processing, pre-sound card buffer?  The raw PCM samples sent for playback?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry I wasn't clear. I would, ideally, like an array of floats representing the amplitude of each sample in the waveform being played (bonus if I have an index which represents the current offset in the waveform).

Comment: The example you posted has excellent comments for what is going on.  I recommend starting there.

Comment: That's more-or-less what I'm doing now. I guess I was just hoping it would be a common use-case. The Mozilla Audio Data API looked like EXACTLY what I wanted, but unfortunately none of the events seem to work anymore (or maybe I'm doing it wrong!).

Answer (score 1):

You want the [web audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) ([HTML5 rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)) which unfortunately is only partially supported in [Firefox, Chrome and Safari](http://caniuse.com/audio-api) currently.

No doubt the Mozilla audio API has helped to shape the W3 proposal but is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension) in favour, I'm guessing, of the implementation of the emerging W3 standard.